# Have one cell represent a cell range

Tags: excel, ms-office

Excel 2003 Question:
I'd like to have one cell represent a range of cells. So that another formula can use it.

Right now, I have an equation to sum the hours worked on a specific project. It looks for a project name, and then beside it, I have a column with how long i've spent on it. This is the formula  `=SUMIF(D1:D10,"project1",C1:C10)`

If you look at the first picture,
I want B10 to say the range of Duration (B23-B28)
I want C10 to say the range of Project (C23-C28)

Now look at the second picture, with the formula.
Instead of having the range manually, I just want it to look at B10, and C10 so I get the range once. This way, I only have to change the range in one spot instead of how ever many projects I have.

I'm sorry if this is a messy problem. I'm not sure how to ask it, but I will be quickly answering comments if people aren't clear on what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

---

---

[image]

Comment: So you want it to work by entering "C23:C46" in cell B10 right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making it a bit more clear. You can enter the range (Address) as a text in the cells, and then use `INDIRECT` to reference them to a range instead of just text.

So enter

```
"C23:C46" in cell B10 (without quotes)
"D23:D46" in C10      (without quotes)
```

and use `INDIRECT` in your formula for `SUMIF`
Here's a picture for more clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Store in the cell the address as mere text.

When using that range, use [`INDIRECT(B10)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx).

See [Excel DSUM with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853874/excel-dsum-with-multiple-criteria) for a somewhat more complex usage example.

Comment: +1 Was just going to say the same thing nice :) can you please edit it so as to make it more clear to the OP