# Using variables in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to use variables in an excel table.

To make things simpler, I want to give names (text) to some numbers. For example a Sock costs 5,99USD and a Pen 2,99USD. When I enter to the cell A1 "pen" and A2 "sock", in A3 I want the result of `=SUM(A1;A2)` and as variables it knows how much pen and sock costs and as numeric values it summarizes them. How can I do that?

Naming the cells with an entered value, doesn't work.

I just want to make variables within excel. Predefine them and then use it many times in a table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have one cell represent a cell range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331141/have-one-cell-represent-a-cell-range)

Comment: Just use your names (`pen`, `sock`) instead of the addresses.

Comment: Formulas / Define Names / Sock Refers To: 5,99.  Or if that isn't what you really want, use a lookup table, and change your formula to sum the results of the vlookups.

Comment: naming a cell, doesn't work. For example when I name a cell, and enter a value, for example 5,99 to it. Then excel doesnt see the word "sock" as a predifend variable.

Comment: @GSerg how do I use addresses?

Comment: You said you named your cells with prices as `pen` and `sock`. Put "pen" and "sock", as strings, in some other cells. Apply `indirect` to these cells as shown in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Name cells "pen" and "sock":

[image] [image]

Add the two using the cell names:

[image]

You say "*Naming the cells with an entered value, doesn't work...*", but it does work, as illustrated in the example above.

You can also define a name to represent a value, without having that value in a cell:

[image]

Then use that defined name in a formula:

[image]