# Use comma separated values in a cell as drop down options[Excel 2013]

Tags: excel-formula

Ok, so I know that I can add some comma separated values to the Data Validation Source like this :
[image]

But what happens if I have a cell that contains those comma separated values like this:
[image]

The drop down gives me the entire cell value.I've tried using :

```
=CONCATENATE("Option1",",","Option2",",","Option3")
```

on the Cell and then referencing it but same thing.
I've also found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/759129/data-validation-of-a-comma-delimited-list) but I was looking for a more direct approach.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA.

Say the list is in cell **F4**.  In **F5** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($F$4,",",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy downward.

Then use **F5** through **F7** for the DV dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: This works, but like I said I am looking for a more 'direct' approach, one the doesn't involve creating three other cells with values and then using those as the data validation. I was wondering if I can just use that one cell.

Comment: I@HaR  It **is** possible with a VBA macro.  But your question tag said *excel-formula* so I did not offer that option.

Comment: I know, I'm not looking for a VBA macro, I am still looking for a formula..

Comment: Although what @Gary's Student suggested does indeed work,I was looking for a more direct solution and I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331389/8596297

Comment: @HaR Excellent research effort!...........the reference is a good one...