# Use INDIRECT function on a Non Adjacent cell range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay, so I can very easily use Indirect on a cell that contains a range(entered as text) and then use `INDIRECT`  to reference that range :
Like it's done here (see **Answer**): 
[Have one cell represent a cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331141/have-one-cell-represent-a-cell-range)

[image]

*In the column C there's a drop down list for each `'=INDIRECT()'`

The range `E2:E4` 'returns' to the drop down list : **Miami,Paris,Rome**

The range `E5,E2` **SHOULD** give: **Amsterdam,Miami** but it gives **#REF**

Comment: Imagine the formula `=E5,E2` as that's what your `indirect` is spitting out, does that make any sense to you? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same like =E5:E2 ? I'm trying to get a "list" with all the elements and then use that list in a drop down menu

Comment: Are you using the indirect in data validation?

Comment: Yes and it works if the value in the B column is a Adjacent cell range(i.e. E2:E5

Comment: You will need vba.

Comment: To use the list in a drop down menu you MUST use Data Validation in the "Data" menu up in the ribbon. Indirect can be used there, but you will have to format the range correctly like `<startcell>:<endcell>` so that range HAS to be `E2:E5`.

Comment: @JNevill ,What if I want the range to be something like this `<cell>,<cell>,<cell>`?

Comment: You can't do that in Data Validation drop downs. It has to be a single range as input. You'll have to get more creative to get your `Amserdam` and `Miami` values into their own list where they are the only to values (say in another column) then reference that range in your data validation.

Comment: Yeah , seems like that is the only solution.

Comment: Data validation needs a continuous range. You could, however, set up a continuous range that references your non-continuous range (e.g. C1=B2, C2=B4, C3=B6, etc.) and use C1:C3 as your validation source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting each value in a separate column then you can use the following:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),INDIRECT(B2),INDIRECT(A2)&","&INDIRECT(B2))
```

This will return your original indirect if the cell is blank and if not it will return both values. (I used column A but you can change the reference